# normalizr returns array of undefined values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, normalizr

I am using react+redux and I am trying to normalize the return of an API. My code is as follows:

the schema is:

```
import { schema} from "normalizr";

export const walkthroughSchema = new schema.Entity("walkthroughs");
export const walkthroughListSchema = [walkthroughSchema];
```

my fetch is:

```
static listAllWalkthroughs() {
   return window
  .fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/walkthroughs")
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(jsonData => {
    const normalized = normalize(jsonData, schemas.walkthroughListSchema );
    console.log("api - response", jsonData);
    console.log("api - normalized dsata ", normalized);
  });
}
```

the response of the fetch is:

```
[0 : {
  name: "name 1",
  ID: "5aa7317906ddabf5f7d76c58",
  username: "",
  url: "https://google.com", status: "", …},

1 : {
  name: "name 2",
  ID: "5aa7346706ddabf5f7d76d5d",
  username: "",
  url: "https://google.com",
  status: "", …},
2 : {
  name: "name 3",
  ID: "5acd9740d53edd2200818bb1",
  username: "",
  url: "https://google.com",
  status: "", …}]
```

when I print the normlized data thats the result:

```
entities:
  walkthoroughs: {
    undefined: {
      id : "5acd9740d53edd2200818bb1",name: 
        "name 3",
            status: "",
            steps: [],
            url: "https://google.com",
            username:""

    }
  }
result: {[
    0: undefined,
    1: undefined,
    2: undefined
]
}
```

The question is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your JSON response is not an Array, but an object map. (It also looks like it's not actually JSON (no comma between objects). Might help to format it correctly here if it is actually JSON)

Comment: thanks for that, it was just copy and past issues. Fixed already